# How to pass page number to ion-infinite-scroll?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, infinite-scroll, ionic3

I’m new to Ionic and would like to use infinite scroll to display data from HTTP GET with pagenumber parameter similar to below:

http://example.com/users/pagenum=1

Can infinite scroll pass the page number? So if it scrolls next it will call next page number instead

http://example.com/users/pagenum=2

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, You can.** Please see the inline comments below.

*.html*

```
 <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="getNewPage($event)">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

*.ts*

```
 pageNumber: number = 1;//default page number

 constructor(){}

 getNewPage(infiniteScroll:any) {
    this.pageNumber++;//Here increase the page number
    this.getYourAsyncMethod(this.pageNumber)
      .subscribe((res: any) => {
        // handle the response...
      },
      error => {
        // handle the error...
      },
      () => {
        // Hide the spinner of the infinite scroll
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @sebaferreras as always for your help :)

Comment: Np, it was just a very small edit, the answer is perfect :)